# Do MySQL (5.6) triggers support 4 byte emojis?

Tags: mysql, trigger, mysql-5.6

I'm using MySQL 5.6.34 with the following settings:

```
"character_set_client","utf8mb4"
"character_set_connection","utf8mb4"
"character_set_database","utf8mb4"
"character_set_filesystem","utf8mb4"
"character_set_results","utf8mb4"
"character_set_server","utf8mb4"
"character_set_system","utf8"
"collation_connection","utf8mb4_general_ci"
"collation_database","utf8mb4_unicode_ci"
"collation_server","utf8mb4_unicode_ci"
```

3 byte emojis seem to work correctly within a trigger but 4 byte do not. They just become a '?'. Is there a different setting that should be used or is this just not supported within a trigger?

Comment: full support for utf8mb4 encoding is only available in MySQL 8 therefore full sopport for characters like emojis only works in that version

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the trigger and structures for any related tables

Comment: Check the `information_schema.triggers` table row that corresponds to this trigger.  The values for `SQL_MODE`, `CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT`, and `COLLATION_CONNECTION` shown for this trigger will be in effect when this trigger fires -- *not the server settings*.  Do you see a discrepancy?

Answer (score 0):

As in the [github](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/8062) issue was recommended to change the settings on the following:

```
connection_charset: utf8mb4
connection_collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
charset: utf8mb4
collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I suppose you could change

```
"collation_connection","utf8mb4_general_ci"
```

on

```
"collation_connection","utf8mb4_unicode_ci"
```

Comment: Collation controls how characters compare, not how they are stored.

Answer (score 0):

Collations are irrelevant when it comes to 3-byte encoding versus 4-byte.

Check `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to see if the column can accept utf8mb4.

Check `SHOW CREATE TRIGGER` to see what the charset was when you created the trigger.  (This is the likely cause of your trouble.)  Example:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TRIGGER t3trig\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Trigger: t3trig
              sql_mode: 
SQL Original Statement: CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`127.0.0.1` trigger t3trig before insert on t3 for each row ...
  character_set_client: utf8
  collation_connection: utf8_general_ci
    Database Collation: utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This trigger might get the same problem you have.

The solution is probably to set the desired charset and recreate the trigger:

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4;
DROP TRIGGER ...;
CREATE TRIGGER ...;
```

And, before you ask, there is not an 'alter trigger': https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/78442/1876